# Rails: How can I achieve this relationship model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to create a simple relationship model with the following:

I have 2 main items. `Product` / `WishList`

The relationship between them is pretty straight forward a `WishList` `has_many :products` and a `Product` `belongs_to_many :wishlists`

I understand that there isn't a `belongs_to_many` association and as simple as this may be I can't seem to wrap my head around the right relationship model.

If someone could suggest a nice way to achieve this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a choice between a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and a [has_and_belong_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relation.

Pick the first one if you need to attach other attributes to the model that will be the bridge (for instance a position, if you want to order your wishlist), or the second one otherwise (more about that [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many))

So it could look like so

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :wishlists, through: :items
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :wishlist
end

class Wishlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :products, through: :items
end
```

Comment: The HABTM relation is not a good option (see RoR Style Guide about it). `has_many` `through` is a better option: it is more flexible, you can add extra fields on the join table, like `is_favorite`, `position`, `priority`, etc etc. Good answer though, +1